# Postgresql Share Row Exclusive Lock VS pg_advisory_lock

Tags: postgresql, locking, deadlock, psycopg2, postgresql-9.3

I'm running Postgres 9.3 and have a table tags, accessed through Python's psycopg2 module. I have a table called 'tags' that gets updated/inserted by two different methods, called 'update' and 'insert.' I also have several workers running concurrently, each of which call either 'update' or 'insert.' Due to a uniqueness constraint, I'd like to lock the 'tags' table directly before I perform the inserts or updates, and I commit the transaction directly after.

So my code roughly looks like (in psycopg2 parlance)

UPDATE:

```
cur.execute(LOCK TABLE tags IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE)
cur.execute(UPDATE tags SET ...)
cur.execute(DELETE FROM tags ....)
cur.execute(INSERT INTO tags ...)
connection.commit()
```

INSERT:

```
cur.execute(LOCK TABLE tags IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE)
cur.execute(DELETE FROM tags ....)
cur.execute(INSERT INTO tags ...)
connection.commit()
```

And my schema looks like

```
user_id varchar NOT NULL, 
tag varchar NOT NULL, 
time timestamptz, 
CONSTRAINT unique_tag_key PRIMARY KEY (user_id, tag)
CONSTRAINT seen_before_user FOREIGN_KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES user_id_table (user_id) MATCH SIMPLE 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

The problem I'm getting is that when I run concurrent workers I get deadlocks upon executing the share lock. 
Weirdly though, if I replace the LOCK TABLE calls with a call like

```
cur.execute("SELECT pg_advisory_lock(tag_hash)")
```

where tag_hash is a hash on the tags table name 'tags', I get no such errors.

Why is it that I get errors with SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE, but not pg_advisory lock? Are there any downsides to using pg_advisory locks here if I can guarantee that the tags table never gets modified outside of these two methods?

Comment: Why do you want to lock the table when you need a different transaction setting? It looks like you need Serializable:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/transaction-iso.html

Comment: Before the `lock table tags...`, are you sure there's nothing within the transaction that would take a weaker lock on the `tags` table ? A lock that both transactions could acquire but both would be prevented to upgrade to `share row exclusive`, leading to the deadlock. A `row exclusive` lock would do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going about this the wrong way.

1. You should never be lock an entire table in Postgres unless you are running DDL on it.
2. You already have a unique constraint on the fields in question

Your best bet is to run the transaction in a try/except. If there is an exception For The constraint violation - Handle it properly, or a deadlock detected exception, simply retry it.

In general postgres is very good about handling locks without needing manual lock control unless you are doing something very crazy.